# Single sign on across two systems/domains

Tags: .net, single-sign-on

I am working on a project that requires single sign on across two domains/systems. The scenario is company A acquired company B. Both companies have their own security/credential login systems.The ultimate goal is to merge company B' system to Company A's, which includes merging product data and clients data. That might take about a year to achieve this goal, which means there will be a transition period before this happens. During this period, we want to implement a single sign on system to allow a client login company A's system to automatically login to company B's system, and visa versa. Can anyone give me any advice what is the ideal solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SAML. This is a protocol and there are many open source and enterprise software that you can choose to integrate into your system.